# Passing updated data in DataTable's ajax post call

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, post

Please consider the below code for jquery DataTable refresh:

In cshtml:

```
<table id="companies" class="table table-bordered table-responsive table-hover">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th></th>
            <th>CompanyName</th>               
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody></tbody>
</table>

<input id="btn" type="button" value="button" />
<input id="hdnTest" type="hidden"  value="1" name="testinput">
```

In script:

```
$('#btn').click(function () {           
        $('#hdnTest').attr('value', '2');        
        $('#companies').DataTable().ajax.reload();
    });


$(document).ready(function () {

    var table = $("#companies").DataTable({
        processing: true,
        serverSide: true,
        ajax: {
            url: "../Home/Companies",                
            type: "POST",
            data:  { CompanyID: $('#hdnTest').val() }
        }
})
});
```

In .cs :

```
[HttpPost]
    public JsonResult Companies(CompanyDto objCompanyDto)
    {
```

The hiddenfield by default have value "1", so first time when the page is loading, method Companies is called and objCompanyDto have CompanyID as "1".

On click of the button, value of hiddenfield changes to "2", the reload function is called on the DataTable, method Companies is called but objCompanyDto's CompanyID still have value as "1".

How to pass the new value of the hiddenfield to the Companies method?

Answer (score 0):

Hiddenfield may not be able to reach the time of change. Try the following statement.

```
 $('#btn').click(function () {           
    $('#hdnTest').attr('value', '2');        
     setInterval(function () {

     $('#companies').DataTable().ajax.reload();

      }, 60000);
});
```

Comment: Please note, I want the updated value. Where are you passing it here?